# How to create overlapping header/content like Facebook's

Tags: css, layout

What is the correct way to create a solid color header that the content can partially overlap with CSS?

Facebook has the exact look that I am going for (notice the picture overlapping the blue header):
[alt text http://www.thewizkids.net/facebookExample.png](http://www.thewizkids.net/facebookExample.png)

Here are my ideas, but I don't know if they pose problems:

1. Put the picture/overlapping content in the header section and absolute position so that it will break out of the div.
2. Code the content beneath the header, but relatively position to push it upward - therefore overlapping the header.

Will either of these work, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to look at their html / css markup.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a cleverly placed background image. Then make sure your tab-bottoms sit flush "on top" of the bottom of your background-image.

Comment: so - just to make sure i understand - you think the bottom of their blue bar is just a tiled blue sliver image?

and if so, what if i didn't want a solid background...would i think just have to make a super large background image to cover all browsers? (ie - if i want a floral effect or something).

thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

Like Jonathan Suggested, use a background image. But I'd like to add that you should make sure you know the difference between margin and padding, which is extremely important for Facebook's theme.

Comment: I do know the difference...but I am not sure what you are getting at as far as how it applies to this scenario? Please excuse my newbie-ness...

Comment: Facebook uses padding to make sure that any boxes that could reach the header background have a nice big white box around them for readability. But margin to make sure that the elements have division between the white space.